# using SignalR in my MVC application to get users latest information in Real Time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ravendb, signalr

I have been searching for a service that could do something like, notify a user (specific user) that they have a new friend request. I came across SingalR and thought this may be something that might be useful to my application. I see alot of the examples and live uses of SignalR are chat application, which makes sense. Anyway here is what I am trying to accomplish here. I have a MVC social application that uses RavenDB as the datastore, A user may request friendship with another user, I would like to update that client in realtime that they have a new request (something that checks every X seconds). I am either looking for a good SignalR example, or documentation (hopefully example) that may point me in the  right direction, or a good service other than SignalR that would suit my app better. Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR would definitely suit your app well.  JabbR (http://jabbr.net/, https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR) for instance may be a chat room but it is constantly reaching out to the database to update/retrieve its records.

For your case I'd recommend queuing up a command on database writes to notify other users rather than checking periodically.  Meaning lets say user A requests to be friends with user B.  First that request is written to the database and then it broadcasts a message via SignalR to all parties involved.

However, if you still would like to implement a timer check every X seconds this is still possible.  See ShootR (shootr.signalr.net, https://github.com/NTaylorMullen/ShootR), a multiplayer game that utilizes a game timer and broadcasts collisions when it detects them.  Granted ShootR is doing calculations on the server at a much higher interval (50+ times / second) it's essentially the same.

Therefore if you want to take the check every Xs approach I'd suggest taking a hybrid of the two projects (JabbR & ShootR) and implementing a threaded timer (instead of a custom timer used for high frequency updates which is what ShootR uses) and then retrieving data from the database and using that data to send updates to users.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Or since you're using RavenDB, you could [subscribe for change notification](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/changes-api) instead of polling.